# show result of two string column in one column with a line break in oracle

Tags: string, oracle, line-breaks

I have two string column and I would like to combine them in one column with a line break, I try chr(13) but it doesn't return my desire result

```
 ENAME     address
--------------------------------------------------------------
 SMITH      3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404
 ALLEN      3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404
 WARD       3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404
```

my desire result would be like that :

```
 ENAME&ADDRES
--------------------------------------------------------------
 SMITH      
 3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404
 
 ALLEN      
 3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404

 WARD       
 3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404
```

appreciate it if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Might depend on tool you use. In SQL*Plus, it works OK with `CHR(10)`:

```
SQL> with test (ename, address) as
  2    (select 'SMITH', '3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404' from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 'ALLEN', '3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404' from dual
  5    )
  6  select ename ||chr(10)||address name_address
  7  from test;

NAME_ADDRESS
--------------------------------------------------------
SMITH
3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404

ALLEN
3425 Stone Street, Apt. 2A, Jacksonville, FL 39404


SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but should I select all my names and addresses and union them like that?because I have around 3000 rows of names and address

Comment: No; lines #1 - 5 represent sample data, you already have it in some table. You'd use query that begins at line #6.